mininet: Cannot find required executable (ref) controller
sudo mn --version
2.2.2

sudo mn --help
Usage: mn [options]
(type mn -h for details)

The mn utility creates Mininet network from the command line. It can create
parametrized topologies, invoke the Mininet CLI, and run tests.

Options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --switch=SWITCH       default|ivs|lxbr|ovs|ovsbr|ovsk|user[,param=value...]
                        ovs=OVSSwitch default=OVSSwitch ovsk=OVSSwitch
                        lxbr=LinuxBridge user=UserSwitch ivs=IVSSwitch
                        ovsbr=OVSBridge
  --host=HOST           cfs|proc|rt[,param=value...]
                        rt=CPULimitedHost{'sched': 'rt'} proc=Host
                        cfs=CPULimitedHost{'sched': 'cfs'}
  --controller=CONTROLLER
                        default|none|nox|ovsc|ref|remote|ryu[,param=value...]
                        ovsc=OVSController none=NullController
                        remote=RemoteController default=DefaultController
                        nox=NOX ryu=Ryu ref=Controller
 .......
 .......


sudo mn --controller ref
*** Creating network
*** Adding controller
*** Adding hosts:
h1 h2
*** Adding switches:
s1
*** Adding links:
(h1, s1) (h2, s1)
*** Configuring hosts
h1 h2
*** Starting controller
c0 Cannot find required executable controller.
Please make sure that it is installed and available in your $PATH:
(/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin)

How solve problem with controller?

You may try sudo apt-get install openvswitch-testcontroller and if needed sudo ln /usr/bin/ovs-testcontroller /usr/bin/controller...   Check in advance if /usr/bin/controller already exists...
